# Android open source project fork – missing references

Tags: android

I want to fork an Android project (a normal application) from the [official repository](http://android.git.kernel.org/). After I clone the project and import it into Eclipse, I still have loads of different missing references to some other projects that prevent me from even looking at the layout ressources (as it tells me to fix the Java errors first).

Is there a way to fix those references, without using *repo* or cloning the whole repository (with all its projects)? After all I’m only interested in a single standard application there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is using anything that is not the official SDK, you'll have to fetch it to get it compile. You can [import in Eclipse](http://source.android.com/source/using-eclipse.html) if you have the whole thing.

BTW, cloning the whole repository is worthed, because you can grep to search for things, even if you don't intend to compile it.

Comment: So the answer is basically “no, you need to get the missing projects too”… – Guess I have no choice then. I’ll try it later, thank you for your answer! :)

Answer (score 1):

For changing an App that is based on the whole Android repo, you really have to have the whole repo with you. Then you can just change that App and make that App, for example using "make Email". That will only build the Email.apk and not the whole ROM.